# Are there hints of the exceptional nature of $S_6$ in its representation theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

$S_6$ is the unique symmetric group to have non-trivial outer automorphisms. It also has a triple cover.

Is it possible to see any hints of this exceptional behavior in its representations?

Comment: $S_6$ doesn't have a triple cover. You are thinking of $A_6$. There is a nonsplit extension $3 \cdot S_6$, but the normal subgroup of order $3$ is not central.

Comment: @derekHolt Thank you for your comment. I did not catch this subtle point in my reading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least the outer automorphism. Irreducible characters of the symmetric groups $S_n$ tend to come in pairs of the same degree, related by multiplying by the sign character. [$S_6$ has](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group:S6) $4$ irreducible characters of degree $5$, which split up into $2$ pairs under multiplying by the sign character. These pairs of characters are sent to each other by the exceptional outer automorphism of $S_6$; you can tell because the outer automorphism swaps the conjugacy classes $(12)$ and $(12)(34)(56)$ and this is how the two sets of characters are related as well.

I don't know how often it happens that $S_n$ has more than $2$ irreducible characters of the same degree. It doesn't happen for [$S_5$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group:S5), [$S_4$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group:S4), or [$S_3$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group:S3), but does happen for [$S_7$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group:S7), which apparently has $4$ irreducible characters of degree $14$.

I also don't know how the triple cover manifests if at all in the representation theory. I would wildly guess it affects the representation theory $\operatorname{mod} 3$ somehow based on some things I half-remember but I don't know any concrete results in this direction.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
Are you assuming that two dual characters can never be exchanged by an outer representation? 
I have worked out that elements in two dual conjugacy classes have different orders and cannot be swapped by the outer automorphism.
But I don't see how this is related to how the outer automorphism acts on the characters.

Comment: In fact, the outer automorphism of $S_6$ does swap some dual characters, so I don't quite see the point.

Comment: @Monchi: no, I'm not assuming that. The character table doesn't prove anything about outer automorphisms, it's only suggestive. If there were more characters with the same degree that would be evidence for (but would not prove) outer automorphisms; if there were fewer characters with the same degree that would be evidence against (but would not disprove) outer automorphisms.

Comment: I see what you meant now, thanks!